# Can I get a job at remote job in phone service company with low english skill?

Tags: job-search, telecommute, remote-work

My english is on the level like watching movies and communicate on english-speaking internet communities, but I do not speak english on fluent level and don't have certifications.

Is it possible to apply and get job at some phone company or telemarketing companies without fluent english?

Comment: We really can't answer this question for you - every company will have different job requirements and standards. Just start applying and find out!

Comment: From my experience calling customer support, they prefer you are not fluent in English.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to apply and get job at some phone company or
>   telemarketing companies without fluent english?

It's possible, but unlikely.

Most English-language-based telemarketing companies or companies requiring English language phone work will require pretty good English skills. A few might train you.

But the only way you'll know for sure is to read the job description and see what the requirements say, or apply for the job and see what happens.

Have you looked for similar jobs in your native tongue?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience calling Dell Support, yes.  But to be serious, my guess is that you'd likely pick up some skills quickly simply from doing the job.   At worst the company simply won't hire you.   It doesn't hurt to apply.   Maybe they'll have you answering written correspondence until your English improves.